# How to remove duplicate search result in elasticsearch when using scroll search?

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch

I am developing a project that integrates Java and Elasticsearch.

And I am using **scroll api** because of searching a large amount of data.
I want to see unique result( like distint in oracle).

How to remove duplicate search result in elasticsearch?

I searched, but couldn't find the Java version.

My code is like this (this is a just sample code):

```
final Scroll scroll = new Scroll(TimeValue.timeValueMinutes(1L));
SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest("posts");
searchRequest.scroll(scroll);
SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
searchSourceBuilder.query(matchQuery("title", "Elasticsearch"));
searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);

SearchResponse searchResponse = client.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT); 
String scrollId = searchResponse.getScrollId();
SearchHit[] searchHits = searchResponse.getHits().getHits();

while (searchHits != null && searchHits.length > 0) { 

  SearchScrollRequest scrollRequest = new SearchScrollRequest(scrollId); 
  scrollRequest.scroll(scroll);
  searchResponse = client.scroll(scrollRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
  scrollId = searchResponse.getScrollId();
  searchHits = searchResponse.getHits().getHits();
}
```

Is there any way to search the data on the elastic without duplication?

Answer (score 0):

Scroll will return all the documents in elasticsearch. You cannot perform distinct operation in elasticsearch

There are two ways to resolve your issue

1. [Field collapsing](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-request-collapse.html#search-request-collapse)
   It does a group by on different fields and return top 1 document
2. [Terms Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html)

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "t": {
      "terms": {
        "script": "doc['title.keyword'] + ' '+doc['description.keyword']"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Scroll is intended to fetch large number of documents and above options are not for bulk data. So you need to perform distinct operation client side(outside of elastic search)

Comment: I'll perform distinct operation client side. I was wondering if there was a way.

Comment: You will have to collect the data in array or list and do .distinct() on it. Collecting scroll records(full index) and then doing distinct in code , sort of defeats the purpose of scroll pagination. You will need to restructure your data , store distinct data in an index